# Change Whole app font (stoping particular view controller)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I am changing font of whole app using  below code in  app delegate

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
            [[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontsize]];

}
```

1)Now i want to stop , if my view controller are  : Aviewcontroller and Bviewcontroller...
Rest it will change for all

2) how to just increase font size as above code make all label to system font , i don't want to change different font type define in each class...just need to increase its size from single delegate code...not want to add manually code in every view controller.

Comment: You can overwrite label font in the particular view controller, just you have to set all label font manually or by any methods in that view controller

Comment: not working in that case

Answer (score 1):

You may try to override the config when the required VC will show.

For example, in Aviewcontroller,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UILabel appearance] setFont:/*New font you want*/];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontsize]]; //reset the font
}
```

Comment: how to remove it so the font set for default labels in that viewcontroller will show ?